# Failed to apply plugin 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'. Android studio failing to sync Gradle Project

Tags: android, gradle

I'm having trouble with my project in Android Studio and was wondering if somebody could help please so I can get it to successfully sync again. I'm sure it has recently updated and now I am unable to sync my project with the following error code:

Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.PluginApplicationException: Failed to apply plugin 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'.

My build.gradle file is:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.5'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My gradle-wrapper.properties file is:

```
#Mon Nov 29 21:26:29 GMT 2021
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-bin.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```

Please let me know if there are any other files you need, or any additional info you require. As always, your help and expertise is greatly appreciated by me!

Thank you!

Comment: I think you should also add this in your top-level Gradle ==> apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'

Comment: Hello Akki. Thanks for your response. I solved it in the end by dialing back my Gradle to an earlier build. I might take another look in future if I decide to update Gradle then. Take care!

Comment: @Velociholmes any solution for this problem. i am getting same issue.

Comment: Hi @Manish, apologies with the delay in getting back to you. Unfortunately not. As per my answer above, I dialled back my Gradle to an earlier build and the error no longer appears. If I update my Gradle again in future, I have no idea if the issue will resurface or not. That's a battle for another day!